# See a break down of managed memory from a running process

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, dotnet-tool

I am trying to see if there is a way, perhaps using some of the tools available in the Eventpipe runtime, to get a breakdown of the memory usage similar to what is available when doing a memory profile but on a running instance of my application.

I assume this is not possible as I haven't managed to find any resources on the topic but just wondering if I am perhaps not using the correct key words.

I have tried using the dotnet-dump tool but I can't seem to find a way to analyze the file to see what objects are in memory.

Below is an image from [MS profiling docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/profiling/memory-usage-without-debugging2?view=vs-2022) of what I'd like to try see.

Any pointers on where I should look or things to research would be greatly appreciated.

[image: memory snapshot]

Comment: Not possible unless you're debugging from within Visual Studio and using its Performance Profiler. Why do you think you need this, anyway? What are you expecting this to give you that analysis of a memory dump won't?

Comment: Thanks Ian! I find this view super easy to ready and understand. I can see, that after my application has been running for a long time and doing a lot of work, the memory is quite high. I know I am holing on to a few different objects but I am wanting to see where I should focus my efforts in terms of which objects are using the most memory. I haven't been able to see how to do this with the memory dump. Is there some article you could recommend that may help me get a better understanding of how to use the memory dump?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JBRKZyf7Db4

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was super useful and really helped me figure out what I needed to know.
If you want to summarize your comment and add the youtube link to an answer I'll happily accept it.
Thank you!